# How to save changes in a DB for C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save the changes here and I am getting an exception error on db.SaveChanges(); I am trying to enter some content to the database and its saying that it needs to be validated.

Here is the error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details.

```
            using (GameConnection db = new GameConnection())
            {

                Game newGame = new Game();
                int GameID = 0;
                if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) 
                {
                    GameID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["gameID"]);
                    newGame = (from game in db.Games
                               where game.gameID == GameID
                               select game).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                newGame.teamA = teamATextBox.Text;
                newGame.teamB = teamBTextBox.Text;

                if (GameID == 0)
                {
                    db.Games.Add(newGame);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the GameConnection class? This isn't an "out of the box" .NET class, so we don't know what GameConnection does or why it might be throwing an error.

Comment: Post the full error,ie the output of calling `Exception.ToString()`. It's impossible to guess what's wrong just by looking at the code.

Comment: It would be nice if you can attach the stack trace for more info about the error you getting.

Comment: GameConnection is the name given to the database class. The sql file is:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Game] (
    [gameID] INT  IDENTITY (300000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [teamA]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [teamB]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [teamBScore] VARCHAR (1)  NOT NULL,
    [teamAScore] VARCHAR (1)  NOT NULL
    
);

Comment: @GurpanthSingh post the error and (obfuscated) SQL file in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @TimFreese, that's framework method for entity framework.

Comment: Its clearly an entity framework error. It means the entity you are trying to save does not meet specified requirements. That error alone is useless,  look into the exception when debugging and it will tell you which property did not meet the requirements

Comment: https://github.com/Gurpanthport/GameTracker/blob/master/Team%20Project/GameDetails.aspx.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stating that **at least one of the validation rules failed before submitting the request to the database.**

What you need to do is check your class definition for `Game` (or database table) and check for `NotNull` or other restrictions and check if your input matches all these constraints by debugging the `Game` object before `db.SaveChanges();`

Even better, add a catch to print to the `Console` the `Properties` that failed:

```
using (GameConnection db = new GameConnection())
{

    Game newGame = new Game();
    int GameID = 0;
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        GameID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["gameID"]);
        newGame = (from game in db.Games
                    where game.gameID == GameID
                    select game).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    newGame.teamA = teamATextBox.Text;
    newGame.teamB = teamBTextBox.Text;

    if (GameID == 0)
    {
        db.Games.Add(newGame);
    }
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ve.PropertyName + " " + ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Could it be a problem with the sql file?
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Game] (
    [gameID] INT  IDENTITY (300000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [teamA]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [teamB]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [teamBScore] VARCHAR (1)  NOT NULL,
    [teamAScore] VARCHAR (1)  NOT NULL
    
);

Comment: You didn't specify `newGame.teamBScore` and `newGame.teamAScore` in your code, so these are `null` and you have a `NOT NULL` constraint for these two `columns/Properties`.